# access remote video from program

Tags: performance, video, streaming, testing

I want to have a stress/performance testing for my content management site, especially for hosted streamed video part. I am using IIS to host the videos. More specifically, I am using the new Windows Server 2008 x64 and IIS 7.0.

The confusion is,

1. I plan to write code to start a lot of threads, and in each thread I will send web request to video URL, and read response stream from server, but I am not sure whether in this way, it behaves the same as a real user using player to render the video (in my code, I just read the stream, without really play it or write to anywhere). I want to test similar to the real scenario as much as possible;
2. I also plan to use real Media Player to render video (or what-so-ever media player), but my concern is if I start multiple Media Players on my test machine, since Media Player will utilize some H/W or some other resources (video card specific memory?) to decode/render the video (not sure, needs guru help to check and confirm), if I start multiple players, are there any potential H/W or resource contention between the players? If there is contention, it is also not actual ens user scenario, i.e. few user will start 100 players on his/her machine. :-)

Does anyone have any advice to me?

BTW: I prefer to use any .Net based solution, but not a must.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

You should use [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html). It has a lot of command line options. I don't know how all theses options are available under Windows, but under linux something like this is possible :

```
mplayer some_url -dump-video -dump-file=some_file
```

It will behave the same as a "normal" player I think, and your test machine won't need to handle hundreds of decompression thread, sot it fits your need 1 and 2

Comment: @shodanex, any ideas how to use .Net code to access mplayer? I want to write a multi-threaded program, and in each thread I will play a video on my site, and I will start a lot of threads to simulate each user to test performance/stress.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the bit rate of your video stream, you can pace your downloading request to simulate video player clients. The bit rate can be calculated from the information carried in the stream, but it's a little more complicated. There is software for stressing testing video server too, such as this [IP Video Monitor](http://www.mocomsoft.com/en-US/products/IPTVMonitoring.aspx).